# How do I get the side of a div to curve

Tags: html, css

How do I get the side of div to curve on hover? The div is like this before I move the point over it:

[image]

And when I move the point over the div,it like this:

[image]

How should I write the HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and we will be able to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded side, not rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508148/rounded-side-not-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 0):

I actually like this question; but, I am assuming you are talking about the white area. This is a great place for a number of very basic CSS style rules, starting with simple (`border-radius` and [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)).

For the following approaches, assume the below HTML structure:

```
 <div id="container">
     <div> content </div>
 </div>
```

If you are looking for a basic, un-animated transition from straight to curved, you might consider the following CSS approach (your may need to apply a particular web-kit to ensure cross-browser uniformity):

```
#container:hover {
   border-top-left-radius: 100% 50px;
   border-top-right-radius: 100% 50px;    
}
```

Above is what is known as "[slash syntax](https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-css3-border-radius-with-slash-syntax/)"; however, it is sort of shorthand: [no slash is present](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) (consult MDN footnotes). The second value is the "vertical radius". In the above case, for a symmetrical look, both value pairs must match for both `-right` and `-left`.